# php $_post undefined index error

Tags: php

```
<?php
$c1=$_POST["c1"];
$c2=$_POST["c2"];

$c3=$_POST["c3"];
$c4=$_POST["c4"];
$c5=$_POST["c5"];
$c6=$_POST["c6"];
if($_POST['calc']=="yes")
{ if(($_POST["c1"]=="")||($_POST["c2"]=="")||($_POST["c3"]=="")||($_POST["c4"]=="")||($_POST["c5"]=="")||($_POST["c6"]==""))
$total =($c1*75)+($c2*68)+($c3*68)+($c4*58)+($c5*48)+($c6*125);
$amount=($c1)+($c2)+($c3)+($c4)+($c5)+($c6);
}?>
```

error on the bellow, how to solve this...
Notice: Undefined index: c1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\ROMS\order2.php on line 43

Notice: Undefined index: c2 in C:\xampp\htdocs\ROMS\order2.php on line 44

Notice: Undefined index: c3 in C:\xampp\htdocs\ROMS\order2.php on line 45

Notice: Undefined index: c4 in C:\xampp\htdocs\ROMS\order2.php on line 46

Notice: Undefined index: c5 in C:\xampp\htdocs\ROMS\order2.php on line 47

Notice: Undefined index: c6 in C:\xampp\htdocs\ROMS\order2.php on line 48

Notice: Undefined index: calc in C:\xampp\htdocs\ROMS\order2.php on line 50

Comment: Read the error carefully. Your `$_POST` just does not contain those indexes. You could use `isset()` to check beforehand ...

Comment: How does the form look like?

Comment: `$c1 = isset($_POST["c1"]) ? $_POST["c1"] : '';` and equivalent for c2 - c6

Answer (score 2):

Those errors are telling you that there are no such keys in the POST array. This can be caused by the fact that no POST data is sent with the request or because you misspelled the keys name.

I suggest you to either count the value of the `$_POST` array with `count()` or at least define some default values for each of the key in the form of:

```
$cN = (isset($_POST['cN'])) ? $_POST['cN'] : 'default';
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try like this

```
<?php
$c1=!empty($_POST["c1"])?$_POST["c1"]:null;
$c2=!empty($_POST["c2"])?$_POST["c2"]:null;
$c3=!empty($_POST["c3"])?$_POST["c3"]:null;
$c4=!empty($_POST["c4"])?$_POST["c4"]:null;
$c5=!empty($_POST["c5"])?$_POST["c5"]:null;
$c6=!empty($_POST["c6"])?$_POST["c6"]:null;


$amount="";
if(isset($_POST['calc']) && $_POST['calc']=="yes")

{ if(($_POST["c1"]=="")||($_POST["c2"]=="")||($_POST["c3"]=="")||($_POST["c4"]=="")||($_POST["c5"]=="")||($_POST["c6"]==""))
$total =($c1*75)+($c2*68)+($c3*68)+($c4*58)+($c5*48)+($c6*125);
$amount=($c1)+($c2)+($c3)+($c4)+($c5)+($c6);
}?>
```

Comment: whn i call all the value turn null... how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use empty() right in your if statement. empty will silence any index undefined errors that result from the input being checked.

```
if(empty($_POST["c1"]) || empty($_POST["c2"]) || empty($_POST["c3"]) || empty($_POST["c4"]) || empty($_POST["c5"]) || empty($_POST["c6"]))
```